# load formatted json to postgreSQL table

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to load a formatted JSON file, in the form of

```
{
"EId":"104111",
"Category":"(0)",
"Mac":"ABV",
"Path":"chemin2",
"ID":"System.Byte"
}
```

by creating first a temporary table with a json column,

```
 create temporary table temp_json (values json);
 copy temp_json from '/path_to_the_file/test.json';
 select values->>'EId' as EId,
       values->>'Category' as Category,
       values->>'Mac' as Mac,
       values->>'Path' as Path,
       values->>'ID' as ID      
  from(
          select json_array_elements(values) as values 
          from temp_json
  ) a;
```

but it shows the following message:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type JSON
DETAIL:  The input string ended unexpectedly.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {
COPY temp_json, line 1, column values: "{"
```

once I erase all the whitespace, the instruction pass with no error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **exact** SQL statement you are using.

Comment: The whole object needs to be in a single line in the file

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto thanks, I know this information but is there way around it. meaning loading parsed formatted json data in a file ?

Comment: Does your "JSON file" contain a single JSON record, or is it expected to generate multiple rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a file like this:

```
{
"EId":"104111",
"Category":"(0)",
"Mac":"ABV",
"Path":"chemin2",
"ID":"System.Byte"
}
{
"EId":"104112",
"Category":"(1)",
"Mac":"CBV",
"Path":"chemin3",
"ID":"System.Byte"
}
```

The temporary table will receive text not json:

```
create temporary table temp_json (values text);
\copy temp_json from '/path_to/input.json';
```

The definitive table will have a json column:

```
create table t (obj jsonb);
```

Some string manipulation:

```
insert into t (obj)
select
    regexp_split_to_table(
        replace(v, $$"}{"$$, $$"}djue748wBc,l;09{"$$),
        'djue748wBc,l;09'
    )::jsonb
from (
    select string_agg(values, '') as v
    from temp_json
) s;
                                            obj                                             
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"ID": "System.Byte", "EId": "104111", "Mac": "ABV", "Path": "chemin2", "Category": "(0)"}
 {"ID": "System.Byte", "EId": "104112", "Mac": "CBV", "Path": "chemin3", "Category": "(1)"}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your solution is working, though I can't seem to figure out what (replace(v, $$"}{"$$, $$"}djue748wBc,l;09{"$$),
        'djue748wBc,l;09') does ?

Comment: @ponach It is necessary to introduce a random string on which to split the objects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're properly quoting this. See the docs on [quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html), and on [copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html).

It's certainly possible,

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT $${
    "EId":"104111",
    "Category":"(0)",
    "Mac":"ABV",
    "Path":"chemin2",
    "ID":"System.Byte"
  }$$::jsonb AS jsondata;
```